# Different styles for different custom policies for single tenant in ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a single tenant in ADB2C and 2 custom policies for sign-in and sign-up. We want to have different styles applied to them. If this is possible please guide me through the process.

Comment: There is a pretty decent walk-through with all the details in the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be required to create two set of HTML and CSS files for this purpose and host the files in a publicly accessible location, like Azure Blob storage or your publicly accessible hosting server.

You may create separate HTML/CSS files for these ContentDefinition IDs: api.error, api.idpselections, api.idpselections.signup, api.localaccountsignin, api.signuporsignin, api.selfasserted, api.selfasserted.profileupdate, api.localaccountsignup, api.localaccountpasswordreset

You can then add below code block to signup_signin.xml files, if you are using same Base and Extensions files. If you have separate Base, Extension and RP files, below code block can be added to extensions or RP files or you can directly update the LoadURI in the base file.

```
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>https://moviesdiag132.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/unified.html</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <LoadUri>https://moviesdiag132.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/unified.html</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

You can reference the unified.html (for signup_signin) that I have added URL for in the LoadUri within above XML snippet.

**Read More:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy